# Read in while loop

Tags: c, io, buffer

I've been trying to wrap my head around buffers and the I/O functions that rely on them, when I came across this snippet of code, that at first seemed intuitive, but once I started playing with it, the results I got were unexpected.

I used a while loop to `read()` each line from the standard input and `printf()` to print out what I read. After a few inputs, the print outs started to get weird, which seemed off, knowing that `read()` overwrites the destination buffer each time it's called.

```
char line[256];
int n;

while((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, line, 256) > 0)
    printf("%s", line);
```

On the third take (`abcdefghj`) it seems printf started mixing results.

```
abc
abc
abcdef
abcdef
abcdefghj
cdeabcdefghj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`read`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) doesn't add a `'\0'` terminator to the end of the string - you need to do this yourself, e.g.

```
while((count = read(STDIN_FILENO, line, 255) > 0)
{                                    // ^^^ NB: need to allow room for terminator !
    line[count] = '\0';
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

Or alternatively you can tell `printf` how many chars to print and not worry about the terminator:

```
while((count = read(STDIN_FILENO, line, 256) > 0)
{                                    
    printf("%.*s\n", count, s);
}
```

Comment: Ah, so if there is no null byte, printf will also print out whatever's passed it ? Basically it wouldn't know when to stop ?

Comment: @monolith937: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

`read` is meant for reading in "raw bytes" and not strings, such that it will not terminate the input with a string termination character `\0`. If you print the result to console, if you have good (or bad?) luck, the buffer had been initialized with `0` such that you actually recieve a string output.

But if the second line is shorter than the first one read in, you will overwrite just a part of the first line content and will get the remainder printed out together with the second line again.

Write...

```
while (fgets(line, 256,STDIN_FILENO)) {
   fputs(line,stdout);
   ...
}
```

and everything should work fine.